# Chrome aggressively caching HTML with .manifest file

Tags: html, google-chrome, caching, cache-manifest

I'm using a `.manifest` file to tell browsers what resources to cache. Basically contains the following:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# This manifest was generated by grunt-manifest HTML5 Cache Manifest Generator
# Time: Fri Jul 24 2015 09:57:13 GMT+0100 (BST)

CACHE:
app.min.js
app.min.css
js/libs/require-min.js
img/leaf.png

NETWORK:
*
```

This file is linked in the HTML as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="/app.manifest">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" media="all">
    ....
```

Following reports from Safari users that their UI wasn't respecting the cache file, I changed the filename from `manifest.appcache` to `app.manifest` after reading that Safari requires manifest files to have the `.manifest` extension.

I'm now seeing (in Chrome especially) that the browser hasn't re-fetched the HTML source, so isn't seeing that the manifest file has changed, so isn't loading the new `app.manifest` file, and is failing to download any of the source. The cache headers (`Expires`, `ETag` and `Last-Modified`) for the `/index` HTML file have all changed, as has the content of the file, yet Chrome refuses to re-fetch the HTML unless the cache is disabled via devtools.

Does anyone know why Chrome is being so aggressive in holding onto this cached HTML? Any ideas as to how I can get it to re-fetch?

Comment: Have you changed the old manifest file (_manifest.appcache_)? This is a longshot I admit but your **`/index` file is a part of the appcache** and it's being used by chrome, chrome gets the old manifest and there are no changes so it carries on. Try to add a random comment to _manifest.appcache_ and try again.

Comment: This was key, thanks @anddoutoi, to understanding that the /index file is part of the cache, and not the starting point for the cache. I've added a 404 response at the original cache manifest location, which seems to cause the browser to reload on subsequent refreshes. Note to self: never change the filename of cache manifests!

Comment: No problem. Always nice to help. I added my comment as an answer so you can mark the question as answered and gief me points ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that /manifest.appcache returns a 404, that's what makes browsers understand that it's obsolete now, they will remove all local cache and reload the page next time, so they'll get it at the new location.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a change to the the old manifest file (`manifest.appcache`). Your `/index` file is a part of the appcache and it's still being used by Chrome.

From the [HTML5 recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#offline):

> **Note:** Authors are encouraged to include the main page in the manifest also,
>   but in practice the page that referenced the manifest is automatically
>   cached even if it isn't explicitly mentioned.

Chrome gets the old manifest and there are no changes so it carries on. Try to add a random comment to `manifest.appcache` and try again.